# python: El programa no puede iniciarse por que falta VCRUNTIME140.dll

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

Estoy desarrollando un codigo en python 3.8.2, al crear el ejecutable con cx_freeze 6.1 no tiene problema al correrlo en mi windows 10, pero al intentar correrlo en otro equipo con windows server 2008 me salta el error:

" El programa no puede iniciarse por que falta VCRUNTIME140.dll... "

Sin embargo al revisar los archivos en la carpeta del ejecutable, efectivamente se encuentra el archivo VCRUNTIME140.dll

A que mas se puede deber este error y de que forma podria solucionarlo?
MUCHAS GRACIAS!

Comment: ¿Ambos sistemas operativos y la versión de Python instalada en tu W10 tienen la misma arquitectura (32 o 64 bits)? Si tienes instalado Python de 64bits en W10 y WS es de 32 bits eso podría explicar el error.

Comment: El primer equipo, donde estoy desarrollando el codigo, es un windows 10 de 64 bits con python de 32 bits, venia instalado con el sistema, el segundo equipo es un windows server 2008 de 64 bits sin python instalado

Comment: Tal vez puedas solucionarlo instalando [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

Comment: Otras causas posibles son la compresión UPX, prueba a generar el ejecutable con el argumento `--noupx` . Los antivirus y similares bloqueando la dll son otra posible causa,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo solucione instalando python en el servidor, el error probablemente se refería a problemas con la dirección de los archivos de las librerias de python, habian varias posibles soluciones pero esta era la mas sencilla.